# Create objects based on input

Tags: c#, selenium

I am using Selenium to make an automation. The challenge is this.

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
InternetExplorerDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

All these three create driver objects. and all of the driver objects have similar methods. There is a piece of code which will run after these objects are instantiated. During one run of the program only one of these drivers get used. I need some logic to do this. As there is no super class of all these 3. I am looking for some other way out.

Answer (score 2):

A Factory method pattern can solve your problem quickly.

```
//Define the interface with the common methods
Interface ISuperDriver
{
void run();
}

//implement the interface on firefox
class FireFoxDriver:ISuperDriver{
void run(){
//firefox driver
}
}

//implement the interface on IE
class InternetExplorerDriver:ISuperDriver{
void run(){
//ie driver
}
}

//chrome
class ChromeDriver:ISuperDriver{
void run(){
//chrome
}
}

//create reference for the interface
ISuperDriver Driver;

if(<input 1>){
 Driver= new FireFoxDriver();}//instantiate firefox
else if(<input 2>){
 Driver= new InternetExplorerDriver();}//IE
else if(<input 3>){
 Driver= new ChromeDriver();}//Chrome

//Finally invoke your method
Driver.Run();
```

Comment: isnt Driver going to lose scope after the elseif?

Comment: No - it was declared prior to the if/else block.

Comment: This way makes me create the objects at run time. But then i have to define run in ChromeDriver, FirefoxDriver and InternetExplorerDriver. Which i dont want to. The operations on all of them are going to be the same. and the methods invoked are supported by all 3 of them.
The answer is helpful, But does not solve my problem completely.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a super class that wraps the functionality of that 3 classes.

```
public abstract class Browser {
    public abstract Navigate(string link);
}

public class Firefox : Browser {
    FirefoxDriver driver;
    public Firefox(){
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    public abstract Navigate(string link){
        driver.GoTo(link);
    }
}

public class Chrome : Browser {
    ChromeDriver driver;
    public Chrome (){
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    public abstract Navigate(string link){
        driver.FollowLink(link);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, it's how I have done it. Means you can encapsulate all your logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following type of classes:

```
public abstract class BrowserDriver { ... }

public class InternetExplorerDriver : BrowserDriver { ... }
public class FirefoxDriver : BrowserDriver { ... }
public class ChromeDriver : BrowserDriver { ... }
```

Usage:

```
BrowserDriver driver = null;

switch (BrowserType) // assuming BrowserType is a property of type Browser enum, holding the value from the set {InternetExplorer, Firefox, Chrome}
{
    case Browser.InternetExplorer:
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        break;
    case Browser.Firefox:
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        break;
    case Browser.Chrome:
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        break;
}

SomeFunction(driver); 

// ...

public void SomeFunction(BrowserDriver driver)
{
    //... your code here
}
```

Comment: This seems perfect to do. But i have an additional constraint that i need to take care of. I have a function that I need to run that needs  the object that is created above

Comment: I have edited the code for your reference, you can call any function with BrowserDriver object. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Strategy design pattern is the one to solve this problem,
it will delays the instantiate of objects to runtime.

[click me](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38631/Strategy-Design-Pattern)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late. But this is what I got working for myself at the end

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using OpenQA.Selenium.Internal;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

enum Browser { ie, firefox, chrome };


namespace SearchandClickAds
{
    class Program
    {


        public static RemoteWebDriver getRemoteDriver(Browser b)
        {

            switch (b)
            {
                case Browser.ie:
                    return new InternetExplorerDriver(
                                    InternetExplorerDriverService.CreateDefaultService(),
                                    new InternetExplorerOptions(),
                                    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
                    );

                case Browser.firefox:

                    return new FirefoxDriver(
                                new FirefoxBinary(),
                                new FirefoxProfile(),
                                TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
                    );

                case Browser.chrome:

                    return new ChromeDriver(
                                                ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(),
                                                new ChromeOptions(),
                                                TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
                    );
            }

            return null;
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string browser_s = args[0].ToLower();
            Browser browser;

            if (browser_s == "ie")
            {
                browser = Browser.ie;
            }
            else if (browser_s == "chrome")
            {
                browser = Browser.chrome;
            }
            else if (browser_s == "firefox")
            {
                browser = Browser.firefox;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unknown browser. Must be ie, chrome, or firefox");
                return;
            }

            RemoteWebDriver driver = null;

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {

                    driver = getRemoteDriver(browser);
                    /* Do navigation here */
                 }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            Environment.Exit(0);
            return;

        }
    }
}
```